# Nuget ITfoxtec SAML & Angular

Tags: angular, .net-core, saml, claims, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have a problem with the functionality described in the nuget's example and my case in particular with core and angular.
I have a front with angular4 and all requests go through there. With which I redirect to the Idp form and he calls me again to pass me the assertions.
How could I capture the saml response with angular to pass it back to the AssertionConsumerService method and get the claims?

**Update**:
I tried to pass the call directly to the back, now I have the following error when recovering claims:
{"error":"IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'AuthnContext' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'value' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'XXX'\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_ClassReference(Uri value) in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml\Saml2\Saml2AuthenticationContext.cs:line 108\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext..ctor(Uri classReference, Uri declarationReference) in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml\Saml2\Saml2AuthenticationContext.cs:line 77\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader) in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml\Saml2\Saml2Serializer.cs:line 661'."}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible to pass the response through a frontend client lige e.g. Angular. 
The response need to go directly back to the AssertionConsumerService endpoint by either redirect or post. After the AssertionConsumerService endpoint have accepted the Authn Response (SAML 2.0 token) you can load Angular client.