# SamlResponse is empty

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

im trying to use saml for our sites login(react front-end and .net api backend) using ITFoxtec package. After logging in on SSO site, the assertion url is getting success message but throwing exception because the XML is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is in your situation. The SAML 2.0 login and logout has to be handled by the backend .NET server and your React and API security is therefor handled by .NET.

Some info on the topic:

- [Nuget ITfoxtec SAML & Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041640/nuget-itfoxtec-saml-angular)
- [How to redirect on backend for Angular application using Itfoxtec to access app through Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847281/how-to-redirect-on-backend-for-angular-application-using-itfoxtec-to-access-app)
- [Getting error Cannot POST in angular when redirected to call back url with SAML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875335/getting-error-cannot-post-in-angular-when-redirected-to-call-back-url-with-saml)
- [Nuget ITfoxtec SAML & Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041640/nuget-itfoxtec-saml-angular)
- [AssertionUrl for AngularJS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795813/assertionurl-for-angularjs-application)